# Use ANY/ALL to retrieve customer who placed the highest number of orders

Tags: sql-server, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have this tables, and i would like to retrieve the customer who placed the highest number of orders.

i wrote this query:

```
select * from customers where cust_id=(
select cust_id from orders
group by cust_id
having count(*)>=all(select count(cust_id)
                     from orders
                     group by cust_id))
```

I know that maybe there is a better way to do it, but I was surprised to find that 'ALL' works with '> ='

In my understanding, 'ALL' checks whether the current row is greater or less than all rows in the sub-query, but I never thought it was possible to use it with '='.

If i use it with '=' or '>'  the query doesn't return me any rows as i was expecting.

But if i use them together '>=' the query gives me the correct results.

Isn't it strange?

[image: Schema Tables]

Anyway, at the end i wrote this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders, customers
WHERE orders.cust_id=customers.cust_id
and orders.cust_id IN
            (SELECT TOP (1) o.cust_id
            FROM Orders AS O
            GROUP BY O.cust_id
            ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC);
```

Do you have a better or more elegant solution?

And isn't it strange the use of '>=' in 'ALL' clause?

Thank you.

Comment: Your queries are inconsistent. Do you want to return columns from `customers` only or both from `customers` and `orders`?

Comment: Plus the last query is not correct. If there is a tie in the highest number of orders, only one customer will be returned, not all of them.

Comment: i want to see the customers, and if it's possible, even the orders. how would you suggest to write this query?

Comment: `>=` is just another way to say `not less than`. Why would `>` be valid but not `NOT <`?

Comment: By the way `= ALL (...)` doesn't (and wouldn't) return anything because not all counts are equal. If they were (all counts equal), then it would return all of them. `WHERE something = ALL (...)` means that the something must be equal to all values in the subquery for the condition to be true.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ yes i was expecting that "=All" would have not returned the rows, and it's ok..I also expected that "> ALL" would not returned any rows.
But I didn't expect that the combination of ">" and "=" together, would returns a result.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes your right. I realized now that ">=" is another way of writing "!<" thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Various ways to write. Your query, slightly rewritten to use `JOIN` and corrected to return all customers in case of ties:

```
select c.*, o.*
from customers as c
    join orders as o
      on o.cust_id = c.cust_id
where c.cust_id in 
      ( select cust_id 
        from orders
        group by cust_id
        having count(*) >=  
               all ( select count(*)
                     from orders
                     group by cust_id
                   )
      ) ;
```

Similar, without using `>= ALL`:

```
select c.*, o.*
from customers as c
    join orders as o
      on o.cust_id = c.cust_id
where c.cust_id in 
      ( select cust_id 
        from orders
        group by cust_id
        having count(*) =  
                  ( select top (1) count(*) as cnt
                     from orders
                     group by cust_id
                     order by cnt desc
                  )
      ) ;
```

The subquery simplified using `TOP WITH TIES`:

```
select c.*, o.* 
from customers as c
    join orders as o
      on o.cust_id = c.cust_id
where c.cust_id in 
      ( select top (1) with ties m.cust_id 
        from orders as m
        group by m.cust_id
        order by count(*) desc
      ) ;
```

All of the above could be rewritten to use a derived table or CTE and `JOIN` as the subquery is uncorrelated.

Another way would be to use window functions in combination with `TOP`:

```
with 
  d as
  ( select c.*, o.*,
           cnt = count(*) over (partition by o.cust_id)  
    from customers as c
        join orders as o
          on o.cust_id = c.cust_id
  )
select top (1) with ties
    d.*
from d
order by d.cnt desc ;
```

or just window functions:

```
with 
  d as
  ( select m.cust_id,
           cnt = count(*)  
           max_cnt = max(count(*)) over ()  
    from orders as m
    group by m.cust_id
  )
select c.*, o.* 
from customers as c
    join orders as o
      on o.cust_id = c.cust_id
    join d 
      on d.cust_id = c.cust_id
where d.cnt = d.max_cnt ;
```